# How to Represent an OSGi Runtime Configuration in Ivy?

Tags: osgi, ivy

In contrast to the POJO world where the runtime classpath is just an ordered list of *containers*, in OSGi, the *containers* from the runtime classpath itself can be ordered lists of *container paths*.

How can/should such a structured runtime configuration be represented in an ivy.xml file?

For terminology please see section 3.8 from OSGi Service Platform Core Specification release 4.

Answer (score 0):

Ivy is a generic dependency manager. I don't work on OSGi bundles but the attached link might give you some pointers how how bundles can be structured and managed using ivy:

http://code.google.com/p/bushel/wiki/HowToUseIvyWithYourOsgiProject

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. I have googled for *osgi* and *ivy* myself!

Comment: Grumpy... Your question made little sense as the most common use case for ivy is downloading standard java jar files. I thought that perhaps a website that used ivy in the context of OSGi would be helpful. Best of luck!

Comment: The link given by Mark *appears* to contain a lot of useful information. Perhaps it would be helpful if you clarified your question.